# Display multiple hidden divs using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code something like this:

```
<div id="specialDiv">
  <div id="div1">
     <div id="div2">
     </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

The div1 and div2 are hidden and right now in order to display them i am doing something like this:

```
$('#div1').show();
$('#div2').show();
```

It works but is there an elegant way to do this other than

```
$('#speicalDiv div').show();
```

Thanks.

Comment: how was your first solution not elegant ? If I were you,I'd simply won't hide div2 to begin with. Also you third snippet of code is syntaxically incorrect.

Comment: What's your definition of elegant? Least code? Most readable? execution efficiency?

Comment: or maybe you wanted something like this: $('#div1,#div2').show()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$("#div1, #div2").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#specialDiv div').show();` will show all `div` inside `#specialDiv`.

However, you don't have to hide the divs inside at all - hiding the parent is sufficient.

If you just wanted to show divs directly inside `#specialDiv` (in your case: `#div1`), you could select those using `#specialDiv > div`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to add a class to the hideable divs, you can reference the class in the show()/hide() statements.

Otherwise, your method looks as elegant as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Put the divs into a class. i.e.

```
$('.toshow').show();
```

Then they can be anywhere on the page and could be other things than divs if required.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what you've already suggested, you could do something like:

```
$('#specialDiv div').show();
```

But a more flexible approach would be to add a new class name to the divs you want to show:

```
<div id="specialDiv">
  <div id="div1" class"hidden">
    <div id="div2" class="hidden">
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Then show them like so:

```
$('#specialDiv .hidden').show();
```